# jQuery draggable and droppable with scroll on draggable ul

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, height, overflow

***Current Output***

[image: current output]

***Expected Output***
[image: expected output]

As we can see in first image, the drag-able `ul` `li`, are in right of the drop-able area.

When I will be fetching the content from database, there will be n number of elements i will have in drag-able `ul`.

But when I try to put `height : 800px` and `overflow-x : scroll` to the drag-able `ul`, I am not able to see the elements which are already dropped on drop-able area.

for reference, here is code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>New Web Project</title>

        <script src="jquery/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery/js/jquery-cookie.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css">
        <style>
            .arialView {
                background-color: #999999;
                background-image: url("Chrysanthemum.jpg");
                background-position: center center;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                height: 800px;
                width: 1200px;
                float: left;
            }

            .arialViewOptions {
                list-style: none;
                padding: 0px;
                margin: 0px;
                float: left;
                border-left: 1px solid #000;
            }

            .arialViewOptions li {
                padding: 5px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>New Web Project Page</h1>

        <div class="arialView">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <ul class="arialViewOptions">
            <li id="1">
                AA
            </li>
            <li id="2">
                BB
            </li>
            <li id="3">
                CC
            </li>
            <li id="4">
                DD
            </li>
            <li id="5">
                EE
            </li>
            <li id="6">
                FF
            </li>
            <li id="7">
                GG
            </li>
            <li id="8">
                HH
            </li>
            <li id="9">
                II
            </li>

            <li id="11">
                AA11
            </li>
            <li id="22">
                BB11
            </li>
            <li id="33">
                CC11
            </li>
            <li id="44">
                DD11
            </li>
            <li id="55">
                EE11
            </li>
            <li id="66">
                FF11
            </li>
            <li id="77">
                GG11
            </li>
            <li id="88">
                HH11
            </li>
            <li id="99">
                II11
            </li>

            <li id="111">
                AA22
            </li>
            <li id="222">
                BB22
            </li>
            <li id="333">
                CC22
            </li>
            <li id="444">
                DD22
            </li>
            <li id="555">
                EE22
            </li>
            <li id="666">
                FF22
            </li>
            <li id="777">
                GG22
            </li>
            <li id="888">
                HH22
            </li>
            <li id="999">
                II22
            </li>

            <li id="1111">
                AA221
            </li>
            <li id="2222">
                BB221
            </li>
            <li id="3333">
                CC221
            </li>
            <li id="4444">
                DD221
            </li>
            <li id="5555">
                EE221
            </li>
            <li id="6666">
                FF221
            </li>
            <li id="7777">
                GG221
            </li>
            <li id="8888">
                HH221
            </li>
            <li id="9999">
                II221
            </li>
        </ul>

    </body>

    <script>
        $(".arialViewOptions li").draggable();
        $(".arialView").droppable({
            activeClass : "ui-state-hover",
            hoverClass : "ui-state-active",
            drop : function(event, ui) {
                saveOffset($(ui.draggable).attr("id"), ui.offset);
            }
        });

        setData();

        function saveOffset(jObject, jOffset) {
            var storedData = $.cookie('the_cookie_data');

            if (storedData != undefined) {
                storedData = $.parseJSON(storedData);
            } else {
                storedData = new Object();
            }

            storedData[jObject] = jOffset;
            $.cookie('the_cookie_data', JSON.stringify(storedData));
        }

        function setData() {
            var storedData = $.cookie('the_cookie_data');
            console.log(storedData);
            if (storedData != undefined) {
                storedData = $.parseJSON(storedData);
                $.each(storedData, function(key, value) {
                    $("#" + key).offset(value);
                    $(".arialViewOptions").append("<li rel='" + key + "'>" + $("#" + key).html() + "</li>");
                    $(".arialViewOptions li[rel=" + key + "]").offset(value).addClass("needToAnimate");
                });

                $.each($(".needToAnimate"), function(key, value) {

                    var main = this;

                    var offset = $(main).css("top");

                    $(main).animate({
                        top : (parseInt(offset) - 20) + "px"
                    }, 1000, 'linear').animate({
                        top : (parseInt(offset)) + "px"
                    }, 1000, 'linear');

                    setInterval(function() {

                        $(main).animate({
                            top : (parseInt(offset) - 20) + "px"
                        }, 1000, 'linear').animate({
                            top : (parseInt(offset)) + "px"
                        }, 1000, 'linear');

                    }, 2200);

                });
            }
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved..

just couple of css hacks and done with it.. ;)

first change:

```
.arialView {
    background-color: #999999;
    background-image: url("Chrysanthemum.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 800px;
    **position: absolute;**
    width: 1200px;
}
```

second change :

```
.arialViewOptions {
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    float: left;
    height: 800px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 0 0 1200px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}
```

third change : in js

```
storedData = $.parseJSON(storedData);
                $.each(storedData, function(key, value) {
                    $("#" + key).css({top : value.top, left : value.left}).css("position", "fixed");
                    $(".arialViewOptions").append("<li rel='" + key + "'>" + $("#" + key).html() + "</li>");
                    $(".arialViewOptions li[rel=" + key + "]").css({top : value.top, left : value.left}).css("position", "fixed").addClass("needToAnimate");
                });
```

If i missed anything else..

here is full file.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>New Web Project</title>

        <script src="jquery/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery/js/jquery-cookie.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css">
        <style>
            .arialView {
                background-color: #999999;
                background-image: url("Chrysanthemum.jpg");
                background-position: center center;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                float: left;
                height: 800px;
                position: absolute;
                width: 1200px;
            }

            .arialViewOptions {
                border-left: 1px solid #000000;
                float: left;
                height: 800px;
                list-style: none outside none;
                margin: 0;
                overflow: auto;
                padding: 0 0 0 1200px;
                position: relative;
                width: 100px;
            }

            .arialViewOptions li {
                padding: 5px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>New Web Project Page</h1>

        <div class="arialView">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <ul class="arialViewOptions">
            <li id="1">
                AA
            </li>
            <li id="2">
                BB
            </li>
            <li id="3">
                CC
            </li>
            <li id="4">
                DD
            </li>
            <li id="5">
                EE
            </li>
            <li id="6">
                FF
            </li>
            <li id="7">
                GG
            </li>
            <li id="8">
                HH
            </li>
            <li id="9">
                II
            </li>

            <li id="11">
                AA11
            </li>
            <li id="22">
                BB11
            </li>
            <li id="33">
                CC11
            </li>
            <li id="44">
                DD11
            </li>
            <li id="55">
                EE11
            </li>
            <li id="66">
                FF11
            </li>
            <li id="77">
                GG11
            </li>
            <li id="88">
                HH11
            </li>
            <li id="99">
                II11
            </li>

            <li id="111">
                AA22
            </li>
            <li id="222">
                BB22
            </li>
            <li id="333">
                CC22
            </li>
            <li id="444">
                DD22
            </li>
            <li id="555">
                EE22
            </li>
            <li id="666">
                FF22
            </li>
            <li id="777">
                GG22
            </li>
            <li id="888">
                HH22
            </li>
            <li id="999">
                II22
            </li>

            <li id="1111">
                AA221
            </li>
            <li id="2222">
                BB221
            </li>
            <li id="3333">
                CC221
            </li>
            <li id="4444">
                DD221
            </li>
            <li id="5555">
                EE221
            </li>
            <li id="6666">
                FF221
            </li>
            <li id="7777">
                GG221
            </li>
            <li id="8888">
                HH221
            </li>
            <li id="9999">
                II221
            </li>
        </ul>

    </body>

    <script>
        $(".arialViewOptions li").draggable();
        $(".arialView").droppable({
            activeClass : "ui-state-hover",
            hoverClass : "ui-state-active",
            drop : function(event, ui) {
                saveOffset($(ui.draggable).attr("id"), ui.offset);
            }
        });

        setData();

        function saveOffset(jObject, jOffset) {
            var storedData = $.cookie('the_cookie_data');

            if (storedData != undefined) {
                storedData = $.parseJSON(storedData);
            } else {
                storedData = new Object();
            }

            storedData[jObject] = jOffset;
            $.cookie('the_cookie_data', JSON.stringify(storedData));
        }

        function setData() {
            var storedData = $.cookie('the_cookie_data');
            if (storedData != undefined) {
                storedData = $.parseJSON(storedData);
                $.each(storedData, function(key, value) {
                    $("#" + key).css({
                        top : value.top,
                        left : value.left
                    }).css("position", "fixed");
                    $(".arialViewOptions").append("<li rel='" + key + "'>" + $("#" + key).html() + "</li>");
                    $(".arialViewOptions li[rel=" + key + "]").css({
                        top : value.top,
                        left : value.left
                    }).css("position", "fixed").addClass("needToAnimate");
                });

                $.each($(".needToAnimate"), function(key, value) {

                    var main = this;

                    var offset = $(main).css("top");

                    $(main).animate({
                        top : (parseInt(offset) - 20) + "px"
                    }, 1000, 'linear').animate({
                        top : (parseInt(offset)) + "px"
                    }, 1000, 'linear');

                    setInterval(function() {

                        $(main).animate({
                            top : (parseInt(offset) - 20) + "px"
                        }, 1000, 'linear').animate({
                            top : (parseInt(offset)) + "px"
                        }, 1000, 'linear');

                    }, 2200);

                });
            }
        }
    </script>
</html>
```